# LINQ To Entity - LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Double Parse(System.String)' method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Here is my c# codes :

```
double amount_dbl = double.Parse("0.00001167");

using (Crypto_Shuffler_Entities entities = new Crypto_Shuffler_Entities())
{
    double amount_dbl = double.Parse("0.00001167");

    var order = (from Order in entities.Orders
                 where Order.BTC_Address == "123" && double.Parse(Order.BTC_Amount) == amount_dbl
                 select Order).FirstOrDefault();
    if (order != null)
    {
    }
}
```

`BTC_Amount` in sql server is string.
I really do n't know why i have such this error :

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Double
> Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated
> into a store expression.

Please give me a solution for both **QUERY** & **METHOD** ways of LINQ.

Comment: The problem is that EF cannot convert `double.Parse()` in to apprpriate SQL. You would be  better off comparing `Order.BTC_Amount` against the string value (`"0.00001167"`) this should work for both EF and in a regular method.

Comment: @phuzi Sometimes those strings to check have leading zeros. So comparing against string is not a good idea.

Comment: Probably not a good idea to store numbers as a string in the database.

Comment: I did it because sql server saves amounts like `0.00001167` with different type.

Comment: Why bother to parse to double when you have string in both cases? just compare the string, trim any leading/trailing `0`

Comment: @Rand Random I think it is better to change format of `BTC_Amount` to float again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a double value in SQL server as string is questionable. Proably then you might also want to compare it as string without parsing at all.
Assuming you would like you to do with parsing, double.Parse() doesn't have a corresponding conversion in EF you could indirectly do it at the client side:

```
var order = (from Order in entities.Orders
                 where Order.BTC_Address == "123"                  select Order)
           .AsEnumerable()
           .Where(o => double.Parse(o.BTC_Amount) == amount_dbl)
           .FirstOrDefault();
```

From the point forward you have AsEnumerable(), it is client side.

EDIT: And this is the method way:

```
var order = entities.Orders
           .Where(Order => Order.BTC_Address == "123") 
           .AsEnumerable()
           .Where(o => double.Parse(o.BTC_Amount) == amount_dbl)
           .FirstOrDefault();
```

PS: I would directly write the double value instead of parsing from a string as in your example.

PS2: Also don't forget, with a double you are unlikely to get equal values. In SQL server and C# side a decimal is a more appropriate type to use.

Comment: Notice, you will load every row from the server to your clien to parse. eg. your table has 1 million records and only a single one would have the desired amount, every single record of the 1 million will be loaded

Comment: @RandRandom, you are partially right. It wouldn't download all 1 million but as many as matching BTC_Address == "123". If that is not very selective, then you might end up downloading too much. In a system where double is saved as string, there are more serious problems I think.